# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library xxx

Tags: php, c

I'm trying to write a custom extension to PHP but for some reason, I always get this error

**error**

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'deneme' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme (/usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme.so (libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2020 15:17:14) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

php.ini

```
extension=deneme
```

**deneme.so file location path**

```
/usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme.so
```

Comment: Have you tried with `extension=deneme.so`

Comment: off course .....

Comment: Did you checked the access? I mean the error tell us it can't open it. Maybe you run php with another user?

Comment: ı wrote zend_extension instead of extension works but ı get an error right now...

Comment: Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme.so:  /usr/lib/php/20190902/deneme.so: undefined symbol: _zval_ptr_dtor